# How to do focus stacking with Sony A7?

Tags: macro, focus, sony, focus-stacking

It seems that software like helicon remote or EOS utility which allow you to pick focus points remotely make focus stacking so much easier.

I couldn't find anything like that with Sony A7. Even's sony's remote camera app doesn't have such a feature and it turns out helicon remote only supports canon and nikon.

So my question is if I want to do focus stacking in software with Sony A7 is my best option to focus manually with the lens ring or is there a software which will make it super easy like Helicon remote or EOS utility.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Sony does not give external software access to the focusing. That´s why none of the available software solutions like Helicon Remote supports Sony Cameras.

One option to get stacks that you can combine using a software like Helicon or Zerene Stacker would be a hardware solution for the focus shift.
Instead of using external software to move the focus point of the camera, you move the camera at a fixed focus using a setup like Stackshot. This can be controlled by both Helicon or Zerene Stacker.
This is quite a bit more costly than the pure software solution and was my main reason to go Nikon instead of Sony for my DSLR.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered Photoshop? I don't know how "super easy" you need it to be, but it's quite easy in Photoshop.

Open Adobe Photoshop, go to `File -> Automate -> Photomerge`.

After Photoshop automatically adds all of your photos on each of their own layers, you then select all layers, and go to `Edit -> Auto Blend Layers -> Stack Images`.

A few clicks, but basically Photoshop will do all the work for you.

Comment: The question is about using software to set the focus points, not post-processing the images.